# Which is the better object-oriented design pattern in python

Tags: python, oop

I've come across this decision several times and it seems that there should be a "right" way to do this. I want to know: in my class, is it better for a method to return a value or to store it as an attribute of the object? Here's my example:

Which is a better design pattern?

```
import requests

class WebResource1(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def parse_url(self):
        self.url = 'http://mywebsite.com/?' + [key + '=' value + '&' for key, value in self.params.iteritems()]

    def fetch_resource(self):
        self.parse_url()
        return requests.get(self.url)

class WebResource2(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def parse_url(self):
        url = 'http://mywebsite.com/?' + [key + '=' value + '&' for key, value in self.params.iteritems()]
        return url

    def fetch_resource(self):
        url = self.parse_url()
        return requests.get(url)
```

If the answer is "it depends on whether you need `self.url` elsewhere", can someone comment on which option is more extensible? Which is more maintainable?

Comment: I very much dislike setting instance attributes outside of `__init__` but that's not a set-in-stone rule.  Anyway, I think this is too opinion-based.

Comment: One could argue that your example doesn't need a class at all.

Comment: Another answer is "Do you ever need more than one URL per resource at the same time?"  Storing it as an attribute means if you call `parse_url` a second time, it will overwrite the old value.  If you return the value, you can store multiple values in your own way.

Comment: i would use factory method, good [link] (http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you've specifically asked for an OO solution.  But just as an alternative you could consider just using a `dict` and functions.  They really can take you quite far.

```
def parse_url(params):
    return 'http://mywebsite.com/?' + [key + '=' value + '&' for key, value in params.iteritems()]

def fetch_resource(params):
    return requests.get(parse_url(params))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would make parse_url private and call it from the constructor to make the interface to the class clearer. Maybe remove parse_URL altogether and just do it in the constructor.

As a general rule, I would use a get if the call is fast and a self attribute if I need to look at the value several times throughout the class.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO (yes, this is opinion based), this is entirely dependent on what you want to express through your interface design. The whole pattern has to make sense. For example, do you plan to enable the user of the class to call `parse_url` and get back the url that would be used to fetch the resource? Or does it make sense to call first `webres2.parse_url()` and then `webres2.url` with the risk that the user forgets to call `parse_url` before and the attribute does not exist, or has a wrong value.

To my understanding, `WebResource1` is more a pattern where you want to split a complex task in multiple internal functions, and only you the class designer knows when the internal attributes are set with a proper value. In this case, it would be better to prepend `parse_url` with an underscore to indicate that the function is not designed to be called from outside (same could suits `self._url`).

On the other hand, in `WebResource2`, `parse_url` seems more to be like a getter function that could be used internally or from outside. Here you could also change it into a `property`.